# System and rvm Ruby versions are different

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I installed rvm and used it to install Ruby. According to rvm my current and default version is 2.1.0 however ruby -v gives me two options and neither is the version listed as the default by rvm. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

```
foo@ua41f725e9ecd517ff31d:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

foo@ua41f725e9ecd517ff31d:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
* ruby1.8
* ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Comment: Did you follow *all* the rvm installation steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the place where rvm installs the ruby binaries is in your $PATH.

Try adding the following to your .bashrc, .bash_profile, or .zshrc or whatever shell you are using.

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby installed by rvm isn't in your `PATH`. That message you saw at the bottom was the system telling you it couldn't find *any* Ruby version. Be sure that rvm is setting your `PATH` up correctly.